# Can't use forward slash in Nano - Forward slash quits Nano

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, nano

I SSH into my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS from Windows10 via Putty.

In my system, if I just do `nano filename` and then `/` it will exit; If I do so `nano filename` modify the document even with 1 letter and then do / it will ask me if I want to save changes before exit. You get the idea.

`sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update && reboot`, didn't make any change so it's not a bug and I think I have something messed up in the system.

[Here I didn't find a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756578/ubuntu-terminal-cant-type-special-characters-like-backslash-slash-semic), as it talks about backslashes but not on forward slashes (I can use backslashes just fine). The answer says it's a matter of keyboard layout for the guy but my Windows 10 keyboard layout is first and foremost English-US... And, I now saw that my Ubuntu 16.04 keyword layout is the standard Linux kernel keyboard layout, so I left it as is.

Moreover, the problem **doesn't happen** in my local WSL-Ubuntu on Win10, so it proves the problem is not keyboard or keyboard-layout related.

The SSH connection is just fine. I basically have no problems with my droplet/sites or anything.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall nano via `sudo apt-get purge nano && sudo apt-get install nano`. It didn't help as well.

### Milestone 1 - The problem seems to be Putty-based:

I host my sites at DigitalOcean.com (DO in short). When I log in to my DO VPS (DO droplet in DO's terminology) from Putty, the problem occurs, but when I log in from the native DO console, the problem does not occur.

Here are my Putty-login's default keyboard settings, I will now try to change them but I paste the original here in any case:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to `features`, and checking `Disable application keypad mode`, in Putty, seems to solve it:

[image]