# Cannot type slash in Ubuntu installer shell

Tags: command-line, server, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 Server, but it has issues detecting hard drives. To figure out what's wrong, I switched to the installer shell session with F2. Now I'm trying to enter a command that requires a file path as parameter, but I cannot get Ubuntu to type a `/` into the terminal.

This is a remote server, I'm connected through VNC during the setup, I'm typing on a keyboard with German keyboard layout. Here's what I've tried so far

- try to type `/` with `Shift+7` (as written on my keyboard): `?` appears
- hit the key left of `right shift` (where `/` is on US keybaords): `-` appears (this is what you'd expect from a German layout, but then why is `Shift+7` not working?)
- `loadkeys de`: I get a bunch of warnings about `Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"`
- now `Shift+7` results in `_` and the key left of `right shift` produces nothing
- `loadkeys us`: back to the previous behavior
- `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`: same results as with `loadkeys`

The keyboard layouts appear to be completely messed up. With the US layout, many keys on my German keyboard produce exactly what's written on them, even though I loaded the US layout. On the other hand, when I load the German keyboard layout, it's even more broken and many keys cease to function entirely.

Is there any way I can type a `/` in this terminal? This seems so ridiculous...

Comment: does this answer your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/756578/ubuntu-terminal-cant-type-special-characters-like-backslash-slash-semic

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` did not help, same as `loadkeys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my VNC client, Remmina. I had no keyboard layout issues with [Vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre) so far.

Remmina has been the default VNC client of Ubuntu for quite a while, wouldn't have guessed that it has such severe issues with keyboard layouts...